# How can I create a scheduled event in phpMyAdmin or SSH on a VPS?

Tags: php, mysql, server, phpmyadmin

I am hosting a website through namecheap.com and I need to set up a basic event which adds 1 to every record in the database. I bought a VPS as I was informed thats how I could get the super privileges needed to perform this task however I cannot figure it out. I cannot do it in phpMyAdmin as it says I don't have super privileges and I've tried some of the answers on here but they don't work either.

If you need more information let me know.

Comment: Sounds like a good question for namecheap.com.

Comment: I've been on the live chat with them all day and they are so unhelpful and they literally link me to forum posts which don't help. They said they could help but of course for $30 for 15 minutes which I can't afford.